# Google Play Services source code

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm looking for the source code for Google Play Services. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've been googling it, but can't find anything.

More specifically, I'm looking for the source code for com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient.java

Thank you

Comment: @rciovati, Doesn't matter. It's **on** our machines.

Comment: @Pacerier Uhm, no. The executable (or compiled version) is on our (android) machines. The source code isn't.

Comment: I just want to have access to javadocs inside Android Studio :( Is there any trick to make it work without the access to the actual source code?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> I'm looking for the source code for Google Play Services.

It is closed source, available in source form to Google employees (and *maybe* select partners).

> More specifically, I'm looking for the source code for com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient.ActivityRecognitionClient.java

Aren't we all.

Comment: Is anyone aware of any public information regarding the types of algorithms used to implement ActivityRecognitionClient and related services?

Comment: @robguinness: Only the Google I|O 2013 presentations, and there was not much in the way of detail there.

Comment: Can you direct me to a particular presentation? It's not obvious to me which one would discuss Activity Recognition...

Comment: +1 from me for the "aren't we all" LOL

Comment: @CommonsWare, Since it's downloaded to our machines, wouldn't the code be available after someone  breaks the obfuscation?

Answer (score 1):

Use dex2jar to extract the files from the app and a java decompiler to save the packages

Comment: Google Play Services from Android SDK has format .jar, not .dex

Comment: But the `.jar` contains just the references to the gms app. The gms app is the input for `dex2jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Java Decompiler plugin for Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) for when I don't have access to a library's sources.

Comment: Google obfuscates the code, so all the methods are one-letter. It's a very closed source.

Comment: So we've all noticed. Never the less, you can still get some solid information from looking at the obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood they released a initial factory state version [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/_F67iLDcVzQ), though I haven't really looked at the source code.

Comment: These do not contain the requested sources. Looks more like some customized android sources for some galaxy and htc device (and sources to run quake on your htc!).